# Test website program performance under pressure visualization

Tags: sql, asp.net, performance

I want to know that how can I test my website (web-based program) performance with the factors of speed and response time when using MS-SQL Server and ASP.net

Actually I want to know when my users increased to 1,000,000 and more, how the speed and performance changed?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of tools to run load tests against web sites; I like JMeter (http://jmeter.apache.org/) - open source, free, easy to use - but there are lots of others - google "web performance testing" and take your pick.

All those tools allow you to specify a number of concurrent users, wait times between page requests, and then specify one or more user journeys through the site. They will give you a report showing response times as the number of users changes.

You can install the load testing applications on any machine; most have the concept of "controller", and "load agent". The controller orchestrates the load test, while the load agents execute the tests. Generating the equivalent load of 1 million visitors is likely to require significant horse power - you may need to use one of the cloud providers of load testing solutions. Again, Google is your friend here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can I use the software on my localhost? I am using ASP.net and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2